# Getting Android runtime : Fatal Exception

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm using following code of contact fetching app i'm getting **Android runtime : fatal exception : main** error at line no 17.

```
package com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public Cursor cursor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cursor=this.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Seccess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

below are my logcat

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist, PID: 3833
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist/com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{6970ad0 3833:com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist/u0a67} (pid=3833, uid=10067) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{6970ad0 3833:com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist/u0a67} (pid=3833, uid=10067) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
>                         at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
>                         at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:4169)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:5434)
>                         at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContextImpl.java:2267)
>                         at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1515)
>                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:514)
>                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472)
>                         at com.example.alpesh_pc.contactlist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
>   Application terminated.

Comment: please share your logcat

Comment: please check the question again i have modified it with logcat. thank you. @TahmidRahman

Comment: please check my ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check permission in Manifest.xml as well as put Runtime permission for api level 23  or more like:

for Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

and for Runtime permission check:

[permission_tutorial](http://www.truiton.com/2016/04/obtaining-runtime-permissions-android-marshmallow-6-0/)

Comment: check permission_tutorial link and put that in your code

Answer (score 1):

Add permission
     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />`  in Android manifest xml